# Getting a "Duplicate mapping key" error on dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

Set off to add Flutter to the toolbox. So far seems very interesting but already I can't get past step 1 of the official tutorial. It says I should add these dependencies to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  english_words: ^4.0.0-0
```

I did that, but it results in the following error:

```
flutter_application_1] flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 32, column 3: Duplicate mapping key.
   ╷
32 │   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

Why? I made sure indentation is as in the example, and tried changing it just in case. It still results in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `cupertino_icons` dependency because flutter already has it included in the pubspec.yaml file. You can scroll down in the file to see if it is present or not otherwise post your entire yaml file

Comment: Right, thanks! The tutorial might need an update though.